# SQL Server: output select table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing 3 differences exercises. Each exercise have their own table and query. All of them places the same file. Whenever I'm running the program, I see 3 output tables in the console. Now I am trying to output only result table from the exercise that I want, is this possible?
Example:

```
Create Table_exercise1()
Output result from exercise1

Create Table_exercise2()
Output result from exercise2
...
OUTPUT ONLY Table from exercise2
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-select-query.htm

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. You have the script - change it to produce the desired output. Or use SSMS to "view" your tables.

Comment: This seems like a trivial thing, but maybe we're missing something that's not clear with your requirements.  Do you just want to see what's in Table_two?  Or do you need a script that does all that but only queries Table_two?  It seems that you need to study up on basic SQL, but I just want to be clear in case there is something more involved.

Comment: Sorry for lack of information. I have edited the requirement.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) since you've tagged sql-server.  You can execute a single SQL statement simply by selecting (highlighting) the entire statement and either clicking the Execute button in the toolbar or hitting F5.  Alternatively, you can open a new query tab/window for each exercise.

Comment: an add to @squillman answer (that is right), you can also simply comment the output you don't want with `--` and run the entire query